# How to put a conditional expression for a variable inside a function definition or outside

Tags: functions, conditional

I need to put a condition for `b` inside `p01, p02` definitions or just state this condition at the beginning of my problem.

```
p01[x_] := 2*h[2]/κ*Log[(x - b)/(-b)] + θ[2]/κ*x + 1/2;
p02[x_] := 2*h[2]/κ*Log[(x - b)/(1 - b)] + θ[2]/κ*(x - 1); 
forh2[x_] = Integrate[p01[x], {x, 0, b}] + Integrate[p02[x], {x, b, 1}] - M*g;
fortheta2[x_] = Integrate[(x - b)*p01[x], {x, 0, b}] + Integrate[(x - b)*p02[x], {x, b, 1}];
```

When executing, for `h2` and `fortheta2,` I get lots of conditions related to `b`. I know it does complain about `Log[1/-b]`. In my physical problem `0<b<1` . How can I add this condition so that `forh2, fortheta`2 make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Assumptions` with `Integrate`

```
Integrate[p01[x], {x, 0, b}, Assumptions -> b > 0]
```

> (4 (1 + b) h[2] Log[1 + b] + 
>    b (κ - 4 h[2] + b θ[2]))/(2 κ)

You have to set those conditions by yourself for each `Integrate`.

Comment: Thanks @Sumit. So, I cannot define `0<b<1` where `b` is real??

Comment: you can do that for  `p01`. I think that would not be sufficient for integrating  `p02`.

Comment: No, I was mentioning about `b` being `Real`. I put another `Assumptions`, but it did not work.

Comment: When you say `0<b<1` you are already saying that `b` is real as the defining region itself is real.

Comment: Sorry for that question, you are right @Sumit. I still get a condition when I execute `forh2`, stating `b<=1/2` which should not be.

Comment: I forgot to say, I used `Integrate[p01[x], {x, 0, b}, Assumptions -> 1>b > 0]`

Comment: That condition is coming from `p02` integration. For `b<1/2`, `Log[x - b/(1-b)]` is not defined within (0,b). So for integrating `p02[x]` you need `1/2<b`.

Comment: Ok. I separated the expressions and found the answers. Thanks @Sumit..